# Merge 13 million rows using batch windows is not working?

Tags: windows, bash, csv, batch-file

I have around 1000 csv files with the header. I am trying to merge all the files using batch script in windows. This is the content of each csv files, separator is (|), each csv files has more than 2 million rows and the total will be around 13 million rows. 
[image]

In **bash** is very easy and convenient, I use this command to merge all the files considering only one header.

```
sed 1d mpage*.csv | sort -u | sort -r > DEST_FILE
```

And in windows I found the following,

```
@echo off
setlocal
set first=1
set fileName="mergefiles.csv"
>%fileName% (
  for %%F in (*.csv) do (
    if not "%%F"==%fileName% (
      if defined first (
        type "%%F"
        set "first="
      ) else more +1 "%%F"
    )
  )
)
```

When I run this **batch** it takes more **that 1 hour** and finally I don't get any results. **In bash (Linux) takes only 2 min.** 
I need help. I am not sure what part of batch is incorrect!? I would be appreciated for any help.

Comment: Use a different programming language, e.g. C# or Python. Or install Cygwin, so that you can use the Linux commands

Comment: or install WSL, or use powershell. Both are much better than cmd

Comment: Hello I can't change the programming language, it's the strategy of company and I have to use only Batch.

Comment: The `MORE` command will stop at 65,536 rows and prompt you to continue. Using batch-files to handle large files is extremely slow.  I do not suggest you use this as a best case scenario for business purpose. I write batch files every day for my company and they support over $16 million in business.  But one thing we definitely do not do is have batch files handle large files for actual data processing.  This is an extremely poor strategy by your company.

Comment: @Squashman I guess you mean by this sentences bash and not batch, is that right? I write batch files every day for my company and they support over $16 million in business

Comment: @MaryamPashmi, did I ever say `BASH` in my comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `SET /P` command with a redirect of the current file to assign the column labels to a variable. You can then use this variable as a reverse match with the `FIND` command.  As I said, this is still going to be slower than your `BASH` script.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "first=1"
set "fileName=mergefiles.csv"
>%fileName% (
    for %%F in (*.csv) do (
        if not "%%F"=="%fileName%" (
            set /p "header="<"%%F"
            if defined first (
                type "%%F"
                set "first="
            ) else (
                type "%%F" |find /V "!header!"
            )
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

Comment: your solution doesn't skip the headers, so I have around 1000 headers repeating all over. I am not sure how can you modify your code in order to keep one line of header and not 1000.

Comment: @MaryamPashmi it worked in my limited testing with my data. I don't have your data so I can't troubleshoot why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: thank you, Can you also edited or tell me how to edit code to not print all the result into console. There is printing out all the files into terminal.

Comment: @MaryamPashmi, I am using the exact code in my answer and I do not get any console output.

Comment: hi, can you plz help me to modify your script considering not duplication records?

Answer (score 0):

you can use PowerShell like this:

```
gci C:\temp\list*.txt -file | %{gc $_.FullName |  select -Skip 1} | sort -Unique > c:\temp\newfile.txt
```

Comment: Can you please explain what it mean gc $_.FullName part? and that's not txt is csv .

Comment: fullname is the complet path of file. Change .txt ot .csv in your case

Comment: How do u add finally header? This merged files should be included one header, also what's gc? Can u provide a solution with cmd rather than powershell?

Comment: All your files have same csv structure?